# Install specific python version in docker container (Alpine)

Tags: linux, python, docker, alpine-linux

I'm a Linux noob and I try to install Python3 3.6.9 or any Python 3.7 inside a docker container. From what I understand, the container is on Alpine.
I tried this code found on a stack overflow thread.

```
apk add python3-dev=3.6.9-r3 --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/main
```

But I get this error:

[image: Error message]